# Merge two URL in JAVA

Tags: java, url, browser, rfc

I merge two url with the following code.

```
String strUrl1 = "http://www.domainname.com/path1/2012/04/25/file.php";
   String arg = "?page=2";
   URL url1;
    try {
        url1 = new URL(strUrl1);
        URL reconUrl1 = new URL(url1,arg);
        System.out.println(" url : " + reconUrl1.toString());
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm surprise by the result : http://www.domainname.com/path1/2012/04/25/?page=2

I expect it to be (what browser do) : http://www.domainname.com/path1/2012/04/25/file.php?page=2

Tha javadoc about the constructor URL(URL context, String spec) explain it should respect the RFC.

I'm doing something wrong ?

Thanks

UPDATE :

```
This is the only problem I encountered with the fonction.
The code already works in all others cases, like browser do
  "domain.com/folder/sub" + "/test" -> "domain.com/test"
  "domain.com/folder/sub/" + "test" -> "domain.com/folder/sub/test"
  "domain.com/folder/sub/" + "../test" -> "domain.com/folder/test"
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always merge the String first and then created the URL based on the merged String.

```
  StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
  buf.append(strURL1);
  buf.append(arg);
  URL url1 = new URL(buf.toString());
```

Comment: It's more complicated because the code should be able to handle all other case already handle by the URL methode as I added in my question

Comment: In that case I think @Anurag Ramdasan / aioobe answer is more suitable to you. Basically URLContext will remove the "file.php". But as long as you able to subtract this and use it as a URL parameter, you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
String k = url1+arg;
URL url1;
    try {
        url1 = new URL(k);
        //URL reconUrl1 = new URL(url1,arg);
        System.out.println(" url : " + url1.toString());
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: It's more complicated because the code should be able to handle all other case already handle by the URL methode as I added in my question

Comment: but the code should be able to handle all other case already handle by the URL methode as I added in my question.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read through [the RFC](http://www.w3.org/2002/11/dbooth-names/rfc2396-numbered_clean.htm), but the *context* (as mentioned in the Java Doc for [URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL%28java.net.URL,%20java.lang.String%29)) is presumably the directory of a URL, which means that the context of

```
"http://www.domainname.com/path1/2012/04/25/file.php"
```

is

```
"http://www.domainname.com/path1/2012/04/25/"
```

which is why

```
new URL(url1,arg);
```

yields

```
"http://www.domainname.com/path1/2012/04/25/?page=2"
```

The "workaround" is obviously to concatenate the parts yourself, using `+`.

Answer (score 1):

you are using the constructor of URL here which takes paramter as `URL(URL context, String spec)`. So you dont pass the php page with the URL but instead with the string. context needs to be the directory. the proper way to do this would be

```
  String strUrl1 = "http://www.domainname.com/path1/2012/04/25";
  String arg = "/file.php?page=2";
  URL url1;
  try {
    url1 = new URL(strUrl1);
    URL reconUrl1 = new URL(url1,arg);
    System.out.println(" url : " + reconUrl1.toString());
 } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: Ok, but when I get the html source code of a page, I have to handle every case. I have the url of the page that provide the source code, and the link pointing to the external page with all cases (relative link, absolute link, query...) Is there a function for that ?

Comment: if you want to retrieve the source from the URL the easiest way to do it is using the  HttpURLConnection class. it sends response as the source of the page.

Comment: My question is related to the url resolve between a path and it context.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String strUrl1 = "http://www.domainname.com/path1/2012/04/25/";
       String arg = "file.php?page=2";
       URL url1;
        try {
            url1 = new URL(strUrl1);
            URL reconUrl1 = new URL(url1,arg);
            System.out.println(" url : " + reconUrl1.toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you read the java doc it mentions about the context of the specified URL
Which is the domain and the path:

```
"http://www.domainname.com"  +  "/path1/2012/04/25/"
```

Where `"file.php"` is considered the text where it belongs to the context mentioned above.
This two parameter overloaded constructor uses the context of a URL as base and adds the second param to create a complete URL, which is not what you need.

So it's better to String add the two parts and then create URL from them:

```
   String contextURL = "http://www.domainname.com/path1/2012/04/25/";
   String textURL = "file.php?page=2";
   URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL(contextURL);
        URL reconUrl = new URL(url, textURL);
        System.out.println(" url : " + reconUrl.toString());
    } catch (MalformedURLException murle) {
        murle.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: It's more complicated because the code should be able to handle all other case already handle by the URL methode as I added in my question

Comment: Then mke a method that combines the needed two URLs just like URL(url, textURL); and your purpose will be accomplished!